# LINQ Query returning Ienumerable

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following 2 classes

```
Public Class LookupsModel
Implements IEnumerable(Of LookupModel)

Public _LookupModel() As LookupModel

Public Sub New(pArray As ArrayList)
    _LookupModel = New LookupModel(pArray.Count - 1) {}

    Dim i As Integer
    For Each l As LookupModel In pArray
        _LookupModel(i) = l
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of LookupModel) Implements IEnumerable(Of LookupModel).GetEnumerator
    Return New LookupEmum(_LookupModel)
End Function

Public Function GetEnumerator1() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    Return New LookupEmum(_LookupModel)
End Function

Public Property Heading1 As String
Public Property Heading2 As String
Public Property Heading3 As String
Public Property Heading4 As String
Public Property Heading5 As String
Public Property Heading6 As String
Public Property CalledBy As String
Public Property ParmName1 As String
Public Property ParmName2 As String
Public Property ParmName3 As String
Public Property ParmName4 As String
Public Property ParmName5 As String
Public Property ParmName6 As String

Public Property ValueFieldGetter() As Func(Of LookupModel, String)
Public Property DescriptionFieldGetter() As Func(Of LookupModel, String)

End Class

Public Class LookupModel

Public Sub New(ByVal Key As String, Optional ByVal Desc As String = Nothing, Optional Extra_1 As String = Nothing, Optional Extra_2 As String = Nothing, Optional Extra_3 As String = Nothing, Optional Extra_4 As String = Nothing)
    Me.Field1 = Key
    Me.Field2 = Desc
    Me.Field3 = Extra_1
    Me.Field4 = Extra_2
    Me.Field5 = Extra_3
    Me.Field6 = Extra_4
End Sub
Public Sub New()
    Me.Field1 = Nothing
    Me.Field2 = Nothing
    Me.Field3 = Nothing
    Me.Field4 = Nothing
    Me.Field5 = Nothing
    Me.Field6 = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Field1 As String
Public Property Field2 As String
Public Property Field3 As String
Public Property Field4 As String
Public Property Field5 As String
Public Property Field6 As String

End Class
```

This is the linq query:

```
Dim lm As LookupsModel = GetLookupsModel(FieldID, lookup, LookupPage:=1, SearchField:=SearchField, SearchFields:=searchFields, SearchString:=String.Empty)

Dim lm2 As IEnumerable(Of LookupModel) = lm.Where(Function(p)     p.Field1.Contains("A"))
```

I'm trying to query LookupsModel and only get the LookupModel collection where LookupModel.Field1 starts with "A". But the following query returns an Ienumerable of LookupModel, not the LookupsModel object with those items excluded. How do we accomplish this and get a LookupsModel object as a result?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly cast from an `IEnumerable(Of LookpupModel)` to a `LookupsModel`.  You have a few options:

- Add a constructor that takes an existing `IEnumerable(Of LookupModel)`
- Convert the output of `Where` to an `ArrayList` and use your existing constructor.

But what's the point of `LookupsModel` in the first place?  All you're doing is wrapping an array of `LookupModel` and not adding any additional functionality.  Why not just stick with `IEnumerable(Of LookupModel)`?

Comment: I want a single LookupSmodel (plural), not a single LookupModel. The LookupsModel contains an array of LookupModel. So I want a single LookupsModel where all the LookupModel in the array meet the condition

Comment: @jslumar Sorry, I missed that very subtle difference.

Comment: @D Stanley this source code is directly from Microsoft Dynamics application and their engineers, so I'm not exactly sure why the wrapper, but that is what i have to work with. I agree with your point but I have to think they have some reason. Probably because the lookup class is used for more things and they try to make it universal. I do like the idea of converting the IEnumerable<LookupModel> to ArrayList and then just passing that to constructor. I'll try that and get back to you.